# Display content with html styles in div tag using knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

Hi i am new to knockout js and i am trying to display the content with in the div tag .
  That content contains html tags my div directly shows all the information along with the 
  tags , it does not apply the html syles to that content,suppose if i gave any space to the 
  starting of the string using firebug  applies rhe styles to the content

```
 <div data-bind="text:TsInfo.Comments"></div>
```

Comments Data is in the following form :

```
 this is the test i would like to test <br/><b> by : Satya Satyavarapu : </b>SDFSFSDF
    <br/><b>Approved by : Satya Satyavarapu On 28 Sep 2013</b>:<br> sdfsdf
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **html** binding instead of text to display formatted data

```
<div data-bind="html: TsInfo.Comments"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `html` binding instead of `text` to allow knockout properly render html elements:

```
<div data-bind="html: TsInfo.Comments"></div>
```

Read more in the KO documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html